# Getting nil date when device time format is set to 24hrs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

I have date in this format `MMM dd,yyyy HH:MM a`.
When i use

```
[dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
```

it gives me date when my device is set to 12hrs format but if my device is set to 24hrs format then it gives `nil`. Please help, Thank you

Comment: `MMM dd,yyyy HH:MM a` not correct format. You should use `MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a`

Comment: I think you can find a reply here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939064/how-to-display-time-in-12-hours-format-in-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939064/how-to-display-time-in-12-hours-format-in-objective-c)

Comment: What i want is, if my device is set to 12 hrs format then it works fine for "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a" but if I change setting to 24 hrs format then it gives nil date. What should i do, do i need to change date format, if yes then which date format for 12 hrs and what for 24 hrs ? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the date format.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

24 hour format : `[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];`

12 hour format : `[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];`

Comment: What i want is, if my device is set to 12 hrs format then it works fine for "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm a" but if I change setting to 24 hrs format then it gives nil date. What should i do, do i need to change date format, if yes then which date format for 12 hrs and what for 24 hrs ? Thank you